# ASP.NET MVC .NET (not core) form fields not being posted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm wondering if you guys can help me with an issue I'm having with a ASP.NET MVC Razor Form that does not seem to be posting all the fields. Below you'll find the razor code and model that is posted to.

Now the problem is that the form does not appear to be posting all the fields. The fields in question are `PhonePrefix` and `PhoneBase`. Here is the form url encoded string after posting:

[image: Form request]

Also here is the model received after posting:

[image: User details model]

Now looking at the source of the HTML (below) that is generated and as I hope you'll be able to see that each of the offending fields do have a name field, which is what I believe you will need in order to post fields from a form?

I'm racking my brains here, any help would be great.

More info:
Win 10
Visual Studio 10
IIS 10
.NET Framework 4.7.2

```html
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim">Country Code</label>
    <span class="float-left" style="padding-top: 8px;">+</span><input autocomplete="" class="form-control input-textbox float-left" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field PhonePrefix must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '6'." data-val-maxlength-max="6" data-val-regex="Country Code must be a number" data-val-regex-pattern="([0-9][0-9]*)" id="PhonePrefix" maxlength="6" name="PhonePrefix" placeholder="Phone Prefix" style="width: 76px;" tabindex="9" type="text" value="" width="6">
    <div>
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="PhonePrefix" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        <span id="{PhonePrefixValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg field-validation-valid"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim">Phone Number</label>
    <input autocomplete="" class="form-control input-textbox" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field PhoneBase must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '11'." data-val-maxlength-max="11" data-val-regex="Phone Base must be a number" data-val-regex-pattern="([0-9][0-9]*)" id="PhoneBase" maxlength="11" name="PhoneBase" placeholder="Phone Number" tabindex="10" type="text" value="" width="13">
    <div>
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="PhoneBase" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        <span id="PhoneBaseValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg field-validation-valid"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "actionForm", autocomplete = "off" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" style="display:none;">
                <input type="password" style="display:none;">
                <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim">User Name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-textbox", @tabindex = "1", autofocus = "autofocus", @placeholder = "User name", @autocomplete = "new-username" } })
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <span id="UsernameValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error field-validation-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim">Password<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-textbox", @tabindex = "3", @placeholder = "Password", @autocomplete = "new-password", @readonly = "readonly", onfocus = "this.removeAttribute('readonly');" } })
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <span id="PasswordValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error field-validation-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim"> @labelDictionary["DefaultHomePage"]</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LandingPage, ViewBag.LandingPage as SelectList, "Select " + @labelDictionary["DefaultHomePage"], new { @class = "form-control select2 dropdown-box", @tabindex = "5" })
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LandingPage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <span id="LandingPageValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error field-validation-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim"> @labelDictionary["TimeZone"]</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TimeZone, ViewBag.Timezone as SelectList, "Select " + @labelDictionary["TimeZone"], new { @class = "form-control select2 dropdown-box", @tabindex = "7" })
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeZone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <span id="TimezoneValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error field-validation-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group margin-bottom-15">
                <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim"> @labelDictionary["Language"]</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Language, ViewBag.Language as SelectList, "Select " + @labelDictionary["Language"], new { @class = "form-control select2 dropdown-box", @tabindex = "9" })
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Language, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <span id="LanguageValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error field-validation-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix element-left" style="display: none;">
                <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim">Api Consume</label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ApiConsume, new { @class = "fancy-checkbox float-left checkbox-size" })
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApiConsume, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <span id="ApiconsumeValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error field-validation-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.form-group -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim">Email<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-textbox", @tabindex = "2", @placeholder = "Email" } })
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger", autocomplete = "off" })
                    <span id="EmailValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error field-validation-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.form-group -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim">Role<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleId, Model.RoleList, "Select Role", new { @class = "form-control select2 dropdown-box", @tabindex = "4" })
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <span id="RoleidValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error field-validation-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim"> @labelDictionary["UserStatus"]<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StatusId, Model.StatusList, "Select " + @labelDictionary["UserStatus"], new { @class = "form-control select2 dropdown-box", @tabindex = "6" })
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <span id="StatusidValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error field-validation-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim"> @labelDictionary["DateFormat"]</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DateFormat, ViewBag.DateFormat as SelectList, "Select " + @labelDictionary["DateFormat"], new { @class = "form-control select2 dropdown-box", @tabindex = "8" })
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateFormat, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <span id="DateFormatValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error field-validation-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim"> @labelDictionary["Unit"]</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Unit, ViewBag.Unit as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control select2 dropdown-box", @tabindex = "8" })
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Unit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <span id="UnitValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error field-validation-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg"></span>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        @Html.Partial("_MultiSelectList", new Anatomy.Backbone.Models.AudienceDetails { Audience = Model.Audience, AudienceList = Model.AudienceList, PhysiologyTable = PhysiologyTable.Audience })

    @if (ViewBag.HasPermission)
    {
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim">Super Admin</label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsSuperAdmin, new { @tabindex = "9", @class = "margin-top-12" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    @if (ViewBag.ShowPhoneNumber)
    {
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <!--Unit-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim">Country Code</label>
                        <span class="float-left" style="padding-top: 8px;">+</span>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhonePrefix, new { @class = "form-control input-textbox float-left", style = "width: 76px;", autocomplete = "", @tabindex = "9", placeholder = "Phone Prefix", type = "text", @maxlength = "6", @width = "6" })
                        <div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhonePrefix, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <span id="{PhonePrefixValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error field-validation-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label class="text-normal labelValueTrim">Phone Number</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneBase, new { @class = "form-control input-textbox", autocomplete = "", @tabindex = "10", placeholder = "Phone Number", type = "text", maxlength = "11", width = "13" })
                        <div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneBase, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <span id="PhoneBaseValidationMessage" class="alert alert-error field-validation-error text-danger padding-0 remove-error-bg"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9 margin-r-0">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="btnCancel" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-primary bg-grid-btn btn-flat model-cancel-marign-left" />
            <input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="return false;" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary bg-grid-btn btn-flat float-right margin-left-5" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And for clarity, here is the model class:

```cs
public class UserDetails
{
    public UserDetails()
    {
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? ApiSignOnId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A value is required")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "The value entered must not be more than 200 characters")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A value is required")]
    [RegularExpression("^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,20}$", ErrorMessage = "New password must be at least 8 - 20 characters long and must include one upper case, one lower case letter and one numeric digit")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email address is required")]
    [RegularExpression("^[\\w-]+(?:\\.[\\w-]+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid email address")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Email must not be more than 200 characters")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A value is required")]
    public Guid StatusId { get; set; }
    public bool ApiConsume { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A value is required")]
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> StatusList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }
    public List<Guid?> Audience { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AudienceList { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    public string LandingPage { get; set; }
    public string DateFormat { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuperAdmin { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression("([0-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Country Code must be a number")]
    [MaxLength(6)]
    [PhoneNumberComplete("PhoneBase", ErrorMessage = "Phone base must be suppiled.")]
    public string PhonePrefix { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression("([0-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Phone Base must be a number")]
    [MaxLength(11)]
    [PhoneNumberComplete("PhonePrefix", ErrorMessage = "Country Code base must be suppiled.")]
    public string PhoneBase { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You have shown [way too much](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code. At the same time, you haven't shown the important code: the js handler that overrides the default submit behaviour of the form and the controller method.

Comment: From your code, the submit button onclick event is disabled, so the form is not submitted by the browser. Probably you may have some js functions attached to it which will perform the validations and submits the form. Check those JS functions. Since, in your sample screen shots these fields contains null values, are these fields not submitted even if they have some valid values??

Comment: Ok thanks guys, i dd not think about a JS function intercepting the form post,  I'll let you know how  i get on.  Good point about the too much code, i though i was giving you all the info you need, i'll have a read.

Comment: @Thangadurai your right on the money, had a quick search and found some JS code that builds the form post from the fields, all I had to do was add the PhonePrefix and PhoneBase.  Thanks for the help.